# Cannot update calendar firstWeekDay Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3, calendar

I'm trying to update the calendar firstWeekDay to something else (as far as I seen the default firstWeekDay is Sunday) but some errors occur.

```
private var calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
calendar.firstWeekday = 3
```

// the 2nd line is here only to ask this question on StackOverFlow (is missing on my code because I am want the user to use its own calendar, not something forced by me.
[Check code+errors screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oetyo.png)

Note: I managed to do this at the beginning of the project with the same simple code but after a while I updated the app on my personal iPhone to check how it looks and behave on a real device and I noticed that the the first week day is not Monday anymore as my personal iPhone calendar is set.

Comment: Your "calendar.firstWeekDay = 3" is "nowhere", it's "floating". Use a proper initializer for the calendar and set it inside that initializer. You could use a `lazy var` var instance.

Comment: @Larme thx, I'll give it a try. I also have one more question. If I use Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent without setting the firstWeekDay at all, is it expected that when installed on a real device, this calendar will have the first week day set as the one set by the user on calendar app settings?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue. Apparently I had to define a new function and update the firstWeekDay property inside that function. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. Apparently I had to define a new function and update the firstWeekDay property inside that function. :)